# Javascript PHP XML, request.responseXML work on Chrome, FF but not on IE return empty response

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I have a piece of code function well on Google Chrome, Firefox but not working on IE version 8, the request.responseXML return empty on Internet Explorer.

my html form:

```
 <?php
 $content='<html> 
 <head>
 <title>Client</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="existentClient.js"> </script>
 </head>
 <body >
 <form id="existent-client">
 Compagnie  : 
 <select name="companyname" id="companyname"      onchange="deleteOption();getCustomerInfo()">
 <option selected="selected">
 Select
 </option>';
        include './Connector/connect.php';
        $sqlaffichcompany= mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT companyname FROM company ORDER BY companyname ASC" ) or die(mysql_error());
            while($fetchaffichcompany= mysql_fetch_array($sqlaffichcompany))
                    {
                        $content.='<option>';
                           $content.=$fetchaffichcompany['companyname']; 
                        $content.='</option>';
                    }   
        mysql_close();
$content.='</select>
E-mail  : 
<select name="mail" id="mail" onchange="">
<option  selected="selected">
Select
</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>';
echo $content;
?>
```

***my ajax.js file:***

```
var request = null;
try {
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (trymicrosoft) {
try {
request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (othermicrosoft) {
try {
  request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}  
  catch (failed) {
  request = null;
}
}
}

if (request == null)
alert("Error creating request object!");
```

***my javascript file existentClient.js:***

```
function deleteOption()
{
//alert( "1" );
var listbox   = document.getElementById( "mail" );
var lastIndex = listbox.options.length-1;

if ( lastIndex < 0 )
 return;

 listbox.remove( lastIndex );
 //alert( "2" );
}

function getCustomerInfo() {
var client = document.getElementById("companyname").value;
var url = "lookupClient.php?client=" +
        escape(client);
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = updateClient;
request.send(null);
}

function updateClient() {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
if (request.status == 200) {
deleteOption();
  /* Get the response from the server */
    var Doc = request.responseXML;
    var x = Doc.getElementsByTagName("option");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 

  /* Update the HTML web form */
        var listbox = document.getElementById( "mail" );
        var lastIndex = listbox.options.length-1;
        var newOption = document.createElement( "option" );
        newOption.innerHTML = x[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        newOption.value = x[i].firstChild.nodeValue;

        try
        {
 listbox.options.add(newOption, lastIndex);  // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE  
        }
        catch (ex) 
        { 
            listbox.add( newOption, lastIndex); // IE only 
            alert( "In addOption(): " + ex ); 
        }         
    }

 } else
  alert("Error! Request status is " + request.status);
 }
 }
```

***my php file included the XML part:***

```
<?php
$companyname=$_REQUEST['client'];
        include './Connector/connect.php';
        $sqlfindcompanyid=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT compid FROM company     WHERE companyname='$companyname' " ) or die(mysql_error());
        while ($fetchffindcompanyid=mysql_fetch_array($sqlfindcompanyid)) 
        {
         $companyid=$fetchffindcompanyid['compid'];
        }
        $sqlaffichclientid=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT mail FROM client     WHERE compid='$companyid' ORDER BY mail ASC" ) or die(mysql_error());


header("Content-Type: application/xml");


?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> 
<select>
<?php
            while($fetchaffichclientid=     mysql_fetch_array($sqlaffichclientid)) {
                        $mail = $fetchaffichclientid['mail'];
                ?><option><?php echo $mail; ?></option><?php
            }
?>
</select>
<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

any help please???

Comment: what IE versions do you need to support? If you don't need to go back any further than IE8, then you can throw away the ActiveX bits from the ajax code; they're only needed if you're supporting IE6 or earlier.

Comment: Ok thanks I'm using IE8 but the user might use earlier version... There is no side effect to leave there right? –

Comment: Dunno why `responseXML` isn't populated (normally these days one would go for JSON to avoid the annoying XML DOM) but you have multiple SQL-injections and HTML-injections here.

Comment: I'll try with JSON thank's. If you find out why it's not populated please let me know...

Comment: Thanks all I find my mistake by myself!!! There is no data submitted from the HTML form IE doesn't submit it... I don't know why if you have any ideas please let me know....